# Why does Devise allow me to create User without providing password_confirmation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm using Devise in my project. Why does it allow me to create User when I don't provide `password_confirmation` in request? When I provide `password_confirmation` other than `password` it doesn't allow me to create User. How to force providing `password_confirmation` in params?

```
# user.rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  devise :database_authenticatable,
         :jwt_authenticatable,
         :registerable,
         :validatable,
         jwt_revocation_strategy: JwtDenylist
end
```

```
# part of my routes.rb
  devise_for :users,
             path: 'api/v1/users',
             controllers: {
               sessions: 'api/v1/users/sessions',
               registrations: 'api/v1/users/registrations'
             }
```

Comment: Requiring the confirmation on is done on the server side with a validation. Thats what the validatable module in Devise does by default. If it doesn't work in your application you need to start by isolation the problem with a minimal verifiyable example.